# unix - awk usage on mac not working but online resource does

Tags: unix, awk

Overview:

- running macOS Mojave 10.14.3 and RHEL 7.6
- awk version 20070501 on macOS and GNU Awk 4.0.2 on RHEL 7.6
- have a file with the following two lines

  ```
  username=jsmith
  api=2343234sdfkljasf
  ```
- trying to run the following AWK command

  - `awk -F= '$1=="username"||$1=="api"{print$2}' file.txt`
- trying to extract the

  ```
  jsmith
  2343234sdfkljasf
  ```

Issue:

- attempting to run it on macOS or RHEL 7.6, it returns nothing.
- a bit of troubleshooting and i found that the double == should be = but everywhere i've seen awk used they use `==` in their example.

  - `awk -F= '$1="username"||$1="api"{print$2}' file.txt`
- using a online tool it does work with `==` https://tio.run/##Nck5CoAwEEDR3mMEWwudaaf1HikCZrKSRCzUqzsuYPPh8/TmRPqRSK3VlKiDUcfxvc5W7bnY2PrpFPmZuAbblu5hAgR07DxPwOjBvUEGj3yl3GyKVYaZbg

Question:

- Which syntax is correct since everywhere the syntax is `==`?
- How do you get just the `jsmith` or `2343234sdfkljasf`?

Comment: wrt `the double == should be =` - **NO**. `==` is the comparison operator, `=` is the assignment operator. If `$1=="username"` is producing no output then it's because you have no input line where `$1` has the value `username`. `$1="username"` is outputing every line because you're assigning `$1` to be `username` and then testing that the result is not null, which it isn't, and then printing because of it. Your input file must contain leading blanks or control chars or something,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Editing the `file`a bit to be more descriptive:

```
$ cat file
username=user1
api=pass1
 username=user2
api =pass2
```

Notice the 2 spaces added to records 3 and 4. First with `==`:

```
$ awk -F= '$1=="username"||$1=="api"{print$2}' file
user1
pass1
```

Only records 1 and 2 were were matched. Now, if you use `=`, you are not matching anythingm instead you are setting `$1` :

```
$ awk -F= '$1="username"||$1=="api"{print$2}' file
user1
pass1
user2
pass2
```

What you set is:

```
$ awk -F= '$1="username"||$1=="api"{print $1,$2}' file
1 user1
1 pass1
1 user2
1 pass2
```

Tl;dr: `==` is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
awk -F'=' '{gsub(/[[:space:]]/,"")} $1 == "username" || $1 == "api" { print $2; } ' file.txt
```

The proper way to compare IS `==`, or `~` to use regex match.
`=` is assign, that will always leave the condition with `True`, so it will `print` no matter what.
You might have spaces in the line, thus made the `==` checking false, remove those spaces first by the `gsub`.
Also it's better to *add* space between the elements in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try following too. I am removing the starting space and ending space in line considering that you may not need it. Then checking if first field is either `username` or `api` then print last field of that line.

```
awk -F'=' '{gsub(/^[[:space:]]+|[[:space:]]+$/,"")} $1~/^username$|^api$/{print $NF}' Input_file
```

---

---

OR assuming your Input_file have Control-M characters?(since your attempt works fine for me and assuming that your Input_file is same as shown samples). Check once if you have control M(s) or not by doing `cat -v Input_file` in case you have them then you could try following command.

```
awk -F'=' '{gsub(/^[[:space:]]+|[[:space:]]+$|\r/,"")} $1~/^username$|^api$/{print $NF}' Input_file
```

Comment: @Lacer, Could you please do let me know if this solution has helped you?